# How do I get mod_rewrite working when not installed

Tags: mod-rewrite, centos, cpanel, whm

I have Centos, cPanel, WHM and Apache 2.4. I can find mod_rewrite.c but no .so and it is not installed or enabled. How do I install and enable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mod_rewrite is by default installed on your server. You can check that with **httpd -M** command

```
[root ~ ]# httpd -M | grep rewrite
 rewrite_module (static)
[root ~ ]#
```

Comment: how do I enable it for a site?